# International tel input in laravel 8

Tags: jquery, laravel, intl-tel-input

I'm using this code to validate the phone number ;
I'm using the Intl-tel-input jQuery plugin for entering and validating international telephone numbers

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/build/css/intlTelInput.css" />
<script src="build/js/intlTelInput.js"></script>
<script src="build/js/utils.js"></script>
<form id="contactForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">Phone number</label>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phoneNumber" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
  <script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/js/intlTelInput.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $('#contactForm')
        .find('[name="phoneNumber"]')
            .intlTelInput({
                utilsScript: 'build/js/utils.js',
                autoPlaceholder: true,
                preferredCountries: ['fr', 'us', 'gb']
            });

    $('#contactForm')
        .formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap',
            icon: {
                valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
            },
            fields: {
                phoneNumber: {
                    validators: {
                        callback: {
                            callback: function(value, validator, $field) {
                                var isValid = value === '' || $field.intlTelInput('isValidNumber'),
                                    err     = $field.intlTelInput('getValidationError'),
                                    message = null;
                                switch (err) {
                                    case intlTelInputUtils.validationError.INVALID_COUNTRY_CODE:
                                        message = 'The country code is not valid';
                                        break;

                                    case intlTelInputUtils.validationError.TOO_SHORT:
                                        message = 'The phone number is too short';
                                        break;

                                    case intlTelInputUtils.validationError.TOO_LONG:
                                        message = 'The phone number is too long';
                                        break;

                                    case intlTelInputUtils.validationError.NOT_A_NUMBER:
                                        message = 'The value is not a number';
                                        break;

                                    default:
                                        message = 'The phone number is not valid';
                                        break;
                                }

                                return {
                                    valid: isValid,
                                    message: message
                                };
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        // Revalidate the number when changing the country
        .on('click', '.country-list', function() {
            $('#contactForm').formValidation('revalidateField', 'phoneNumber');
        });
});
</script>
```

But I ger this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).find(...).intlTelInput is not a function
```

I don't know what is the problem,
I have had this error quite a few times and am not sure how to handle it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Basically the error is informing you that a function is being called on a object type that the function has not been declared on.

The `intlTelInput` plugin registers itself with the `window` object and so you need to call the function on the `window` object passing it the element you want to work with.

```js
window.intlTelInput($('#contactForm').find('[name="phoneNumber"]')[0], {
  utilsScript: 'build/js/utils.js',
  autoPlaceholder: true,
  preferredCountries: ['fr', 'us', 'gb']
});
```

Note that `.find()` returns an array of elements it finds so you need to specify the first index, alternatively just use vanilla JS.

```js
window.intlTelInput(document.querySelector('#phoneNumber'), {
  utilsScript: 'build/js/utils.js',
  autoPlaceholder: true,
  preferredCountries: ['fr', 'us', 'gb']
});
```

Check out a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1n4j7sw8/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, when I did what you mentioned, it works but it gives me an other error formValidation is not a function

Comment: @user14053977 That is unrelated and again, likely be because you're calling `formValidation` on an object type that doesn't have a `formValidation` function defined on it.

Comment: I replaced the line '  $('#contactForm')
        .formValidation({'  By ' window.formValidation($('#contactForm')[0], {' and doesn't work

Comment: That's a separate issue from your original question.  :)